# 95% accurate with a 5% deviation of the mean

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, terminology, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

> 95% accurate with a 5% deviation of the mean

I am fairly new to statistics and I noticed this word choice that I have difficulty in understanding; looking it up only raises more questions.

Does this mean that there is a 5% significance?

UPDATE
This is used to describe a Mann-Whitney U test,

Comment: Those terms are vague. Can you provide the context where this word choice occurred?

Comment: 1. This is presently difficult to answer -- context may help a lot.  2 Why do you have the "Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney" tag? That may be important information.

Answer (score 1):

In contexts like this a precise reference and fuller context are invaluable.

Unfortunately the only brief interpretation of

> Assuming that the results are 95% accurate with a 5% deviation of the
>   mean

that makes sense to me is that whoever is writing is (to put it as politely as possible) over-confident about their understanding of statistics. Less politely, it looks like meaningless nonsense.

If one works harder and is generous in interpretation, some guesses can be made.

**Executive summary: This is at best muddled thinking: The whole phrase can be ignored without any loss of understanding.**

Dissecting the corpus:

**95% accurate**

At first sight this is meaningless without definitions.

In principle, there might be circumstances in which you can say that 95% of your data are accurate and 5% not, with some definition of accuracy and some independent measurements that establish which values are accurate or not. Thought experiment: Measure some objects crudely and then precisely with a method thought to be state of the art. Then compare crude and precise measurements. But that doesn't seem to be at all what is implied here.

At best, 5% (a significance level) is being subtracted from 100% to give an "accuracy" level, i.e. accuracy is being defined on the fly as the complement of significance. That would be a non-standard definition of accuracy, which in most statistical contexts means just lack of bias, or being correct on average, and applies to measurement, not significance testing.

In weaker texts and papers I see wording like "significant at the 95% confidence level" and that may be the intended flavour.

Alternatively, the entire statement just boils down to

if we choose a 5% critical or threshold significance level, then a result with P < 0.05 is regarded as significant.

which is correct and follows from the definitions of each term. The wording could be improved, but the meaning makes sense.

**5% deviation of the mean**

This is likely to be too muddled even to invite painstaking exegesis such as scholars try to apply to enigmatic documents. Whoever is writing may be elevating the fact that some of the best known significance tests compare means to a general statement about significance tests. Why not ask them?

Means are not being compared in a Mann-Whitney test any way (without some very strong extra assumptions!).